# Disabling clickable buttons in Gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

I want to passive the clickability of the buttons in the gridview I use, how can I do this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd2eC.jpg)

To make the buttons that appear in the photo not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using buttons, you can use TextView with white background and rounded corners.
Also, if you want to give elevation, you can wrap Textview inside MaterialCardView with rounded corners.